# Do Pathfinder supplements have a dependency order?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-settings, optional-rules

I want to start GMing for 3 friends, and I was wondering if there is a certain order for the way the *Pathfinder Core Rule Book* material should be expanded by supplements.

That is, can I just pick supplements randomly and use them in my campaign? Or is there an order in which, for example, the *Advanced*, *Ultimate*, and *Inner Sea* series should be introduced?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take a the [tour]. Given the vast amount of material available for *Pathfinder*, this is an excellent first question. It looks like you've already accepted an answer, which is fine, but there's some debate on whether early acceptance has a chilling effect on later answers. In short, if another later answer is posted that you like better, feel free to accept a different one instead. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: I am surely keeping an eye on this question and if a more complex and complete answer appears I will select that one.

Comment: I made a substantial edit to this question. I feared its closure because it used the forbidden term *recommendation*, and that's something the site no longer handles. If the question no longer asks what you want it to ask, please edit it further or rollback.

Comment: I've removed the remaining parts asking for recommendations (even without the word, it still was), and refocused it on the non-recommendation part.

Comment: That’s a fantastic edit, this is a far-superior question now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For most books, no, they dont have any dependency

Most Pathfinder hardcover books are rules books (as opposed to setting books) and have little or no dependency on other books. But a few requirements can be found in a book or another, like one book introducing archetypes that useful to a class introduced on another book published before.

---

- **Advanced Players Guide**: This requires only the core rulebook, as many of the new classes (alchemist, cavalier, witch, summoner, etc) will make references to those in the core rules, and you need the core book anyway for the majority of the rules. Also, this book introduces how class **archetypes** and **traits** works, though traits rules are simple and can be found online, archetype rules are presented (and sometimes better explained) again on every book after this. So, remember that when an alchemist archetype shows up on *Ultimate Combat* later, that if you don't have the *Advanced Players Guide*, you won't have any use for those pages;
- **Ultimate Combat**: This book introduces the **samurai, gunslinger and ninja**. Samurai will *not* require the *Advanced Players Guide*, as it is based on the cavalier but has all the rules on this book, but it mentions that samurai can pick **cavalier orders** from the previous book, and as such, you will be limited to only two samurai orders otherwise;
- **Ultimate Magic**: This introduces the **magus**, and a bunch of optional rules, new feats and archetypes. Otherwise has no dependency on other books;
- **Ultimate Campaign** is pretty much stand-alone, you will see mentions of other classes introduced later, but they are not rules references, so they can be ignored if not allowed in your games. Otherwise, the book introduces campaign-centric mechanics (kingdom building, mass combat, relationships, reputation, downtime, etc);
- **Advanced Class Guide**: This introduces **hybrid classes** (like cleric+fighter) and will require the *Advanced Players Guide* for a few of those combinations, like investigators (rogue+alchemist), shaman (witch+druid) or even the swashbuckler (fighter+gunslinger). Most of their mechanics can be understood by this book alone, but others will mention abilities from the *Advanced Players Guide*, like a shaman's list of hexes (found under the witch class);
- **Occult Adventures**: This introduces occult classes and psychic spellcasting, along with a few new game mechanics (rituals, chakras, mindscapes, etc) unique to this book. Otherwise has no dependency on other books;
- **Ultimate Intrigue**: This introduces the **vigilante** class, dozens of new optional mechanics, similarly to *Ultimate Campaign* or the *Occult Adventures*, most of which have been published on *Adventure Paths* and are reprints or have been updated.
- **Horror Adventures**: This brings no new classes, but several archetypes, feats, and spells, most of which work best at the GM's hands. It introduces the *corruption* mechanic and a few new optional subsystems. Again, no dependency on other books other than what has already been mentioned;
- **Ultimate Wilderness**: This introduces the **shifter** a class that is like a nature monk or paladin, compared to a ranger or druid. Again, lots of archetypes, feats and spells that won't be relevant unless you own the books that introduce those classes. The game also brings new optional subsystems for wilderness survival, like milking poison from creatures, collecting trophies, and collecting herbs to create potions;
- **Mythic Adventures**: This book introduces **mythic rules**, which are a way to add awesomeness to your game in the form of epic powers and enemies (keep in mind that they are completely overpowered and broken, though). It is almost entirely optional and no mechanic found here is necessary, except for a few mythic monsters published on bestiaries 4, 5 and 6 (mostly, demigods of some sort);
- **Unchained**: This book is almost entirely optional (personally, I didn't even get the pdf) and the only requirement is the **unchained summoner** for Pathfinder Society. Otherwise, its a few alternate rules for previously released classes (fighters, barbarians, rogues, monks and summoners).

(Before someone comments *But you forgot [this other book]!*, this is no exhaustive list of Pathfinder books)

---

### Feats, most likely

*Many* of those books introduces new feats, and many are related or required to feats published on previous books. So by skipping some books, you will be limited in your feat selection. Just keep in mind that most hardcovers are under the OGL and those feats can be found at [paizo's PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/).

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the mythic rules are unimaginably busted, competitive even with 3.5’s awful epic rules. Otherwise describing it as “awesomeness” might give some poor folks the misconception that the book will improve their game...

Comment: Thats a matter of opinion. I love *some* of the mythic stuff introduced by that book. Would I use mythic rules as presented by the book? No. Have I used mythic rules in a completely different way? Yes, and everybody loved it. Regardnless, noted.

Answer (score 0):

If you and all of your players are new to the game, I'd recommend just sticking with the PCRB since anything more than that tends to be rather overwhelming.

If you want to add another book, I'd go with Advanced since it really fleshes out existing content as opposed to just adding more. After that, Ultimate (for the same reason) and finally Inner Sea for some extra content.

Comment: I have played some Starfinder but sadly the GM could not run the campaign anymore (personal reasons) and I was thinking of starting a Pathfinder one (I like more the fantasy setting). We have two players with a decent amount of experience (but not veterans), a 100% newbie and me.

Comment: Then I'd only omit Inner Seas, since it just add new (quite setting specific) content. The other 2 provide a more all-fitting set of content, which is good no matter the campaign you have planned.

Edit: Unless you plan to actually play a Sea-related campaign, then obviously  the Inner Seas book is very fitting.

Comment: Note that the question has changed, so that this answer is no longer really answering the question.